# Using Local Prerender.io with Backbone SPA and Maintaining Functionality

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, phantomjs, prerender

We've built a Backbone.js app which is working nicely, except for the usual lack of crawl-ability from Googlebot, etc.

We found Prerender.io and their associated github repo (https://github.com/prerender/prerender) and are taking it for a spin. So far we've got the basic Prerender server up and running.

Now, **we'd like to maintain JS SPA functionality for JS-enabled browsers.** How would we go about this?

So far we've tried disabling the `server.use(prerender.removeScriptTags());` line in server.js. This works, sort of, except for some issues loading require.js which breaks the rest of the app's loading, I think.

Also, Prerender appears to be inlining all of our require.js bits—the original page just uses a `app-loader.js` file to bootstrap everything else.

**Ideally, what we want is that the app is loaded, parsed, executed, rendered, and delivered to the client with event bindings and such intact.** Is this feasible, and if so, how would we do it?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Your Prerender server shouldn't be serving anything to your users. If you install the correct middleware, prerendered pages will only be served to crawlers. Users will get the normal JS pages and their browsers will load everything from there.